# CRM Dynamics IOrganizationService SOAP Execute fails with the latest SDK

Tags: soap, dynamics-365

I have been using the latest Xrm sdk to access the metadata of my company's dynamics 365 account. This has been working well for some time, however it has broken all of a sudden roughly 3 weeks ago. There has been no code changes. This only means something has changed in their side.

Following is the code that has been used and it is very simple. The only information I have got till now is that their Security Protocol has changed to Tls12 and therefore tried to set that info before Organization Service object is created like so

```
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But that has no influence either.

```
        var sc = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration<IOrganizationService>(new Uri("soap-url-from-365-developer-resources"));
        var cc = new ClientCredentials();
        cc.UserName.UserName = "username";
        cc.UserName.Password = "password";
        var organizationServiceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(sc, cc);
        organizationServiceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();
        RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest request = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest()
        {
            EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes,
            RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
        };

        try
        {

            using (var organizationServiceContext = new CrmOrganizationServiceContext(organizationServiceProxy))
            {
                RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse response = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)organizationServiceContext.Execute(request);
                var entities = response.EntityMetadata
                                       .Where(x => x.DisplayName.UserLocalizedLabel != null &&
                                                   !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.DisplayName.UserLocalizedLabel.Label)
                                              )
                                       .ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetAllEntities {0}", ex.Message);            }
```

The error during Execute is as follows

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://macfar.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl&sdkversion=9'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at  System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataLocationRetriever.DownloadMetadata(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataRetriever.Retrieve(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.MetadataRetriever.Retrieve(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.ResolveNext(ResolveCallState resolveCallState)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient.GetMetadata(MetadataRetriever retriever)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceMetadataUtility.RetrieveServiceEndpointMetadata(Type contractType, Uri serviceUri, Boolean checkForSecondary)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1..ctor(Uri serviceUri, Boolean checkForSecondary)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceConfiguration..ctor(Uri serviceUri, Boolean enableProxyTypes, Assembly assembly)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration[TService](Uri serviceUri, Boolean enableProxyTypes, Assembly assembly)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1..ctor(Uri uri, Uri homeRealmUri, ClientCredentials clientCredentials, ClientCredentials deviceCredentials)
```

I have tried everything that comes up googling this error message, however in vain. Therefore any help to work around this issue is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been quite a few changes in the SDK compatibility in the last year.

You will need to make sure you have the right SDK version to match your .Net Framework and CRM versions.

[Dynamics 365 SDK Backwards Compatibility](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2017/02/01/dynamics-365-sdk-backwards-compatibility/)

> With the deprecation of Azure Access Control Service (ACS), we have to
>   modify our SDK authentication code by removing all references to ACS.
>   Effective from versions Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2016 Update 1
>   (v8.1.1) and Microsoft Dynamics 365 (v8.2), we removed Live ID support
>   and ACS dependencies on the server-side.
>
> We also removed Microsoft.Xrm.Client from the CRM 2016 (8.x) SDK
>   client because it was not compliant with the OAuth changes, and
>   replaced it with Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector. You can use the
>   current Microsoft Dynamics 365 Software Development Kit (SDK) to
>   access Microsoft Dynamics CRM back to version 6.x for both auth and
>   messaging.
>
> When upgrading to Dynamics 365, make sure you use the latest Microsoft
>   Dynamics 365 Software Development Kit (SDK). The following outlines
>   the current supported matrix for other SDK clients:

[image]

Comment: thanks a ton, I guess the key takeaway was to use Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector. This adds other dlls when installed via nuget and we need to add ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; before CrmServiceClient is instantiated. This solved the issue.

Comment: @SrivathsaHarishVenkataramana; For what its worth I've never had to add `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` so you may be able to remove it